# Можно ли кодировать в Base64 символы с десятичными кодами, большими, чем 255?

Tags: кодировка, base64

При кодировании строки в Base64, код каждого символа превращается в 8 бит. 
А максимальное десятичное число, представленное восемью битами - это 255 (1111 1111).

Для большинства ситуаций 255 символов хватит за глаза, чтобы одновременно представить и латиницу и местный алфавит, однако, что произойдёт, если я использую какую-то оригинальную схему кодировки, в которой есть, к примеру, символ под кодом 789? Как поведёт себя алгоритм, и смогу ли я восстановить исходный набор байт обратно?

Comment: Base64 принимает на вход последовательность байтов, и для каждых трех входных байтов выдает четыре ascii символа (при декодировании все наоборот). Как представлять эту последовательность байтов, дело ваше.

Comment: Нельзя конечно, потому что в одном байте 8 бит. Просто используйте UTF-8

Comment: И да, base64 никогда не работал с символами, он работает с байтами и только с байтами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже было отмечен в комментариях, base64 работает с байтами, а не символами. И придуман был именно для ситуации, когда нужно передать поток бинарных данных, через канал, где допустимы только ASCII-символы, например, через цифровой телеграф.

По поводу схемы кодирования - не нужно придумывать свои, когда они уже давно есть. Для Unicode это UTF. Их несколько, самые популярные - это UTF-8 (в мире Unix) и UTF-16 (в Windows). UTF - это как раз способ однозначно сопоставить между собой код символа в диапазоне от нуля до примерно миллиарда и последовательность не более чем из 4 байт.

А уже закодированная байтовая последовательность кодируется при помощи base64

Comment: Есть и более экзотические кодировки, например, UTF-7, позволяющая сразу преобразовать в последовательность ASCII-символов.